# adonis.js "E_INVALID_METHOD: logout method is not implemented by jwt scheme

Tags: authentication, jwt, adonis.js

I am using:

- adonis 4.1.0,
- jwt scheme, mongodb

Registration and login works fine, logout fail in my `authController.js`:

```
async logout ({ request, response, auth }) {
    await auth.logout()//falls here
    return response.send('success')
  }
```

> code: "E_INVALID_METHOD"
>
> message: "E_INVALID_METHOD: logout method is not implemented by jwt scheme↵> More
>
> details: https://err.sh/adonisjs/errors/E_INVALID_METHOD"
>
> status: 500

What can possibly get wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

> auth.logout() Is Only Available for Session based auth.

For JWT you need to revoke the RefreshToken** for a user

> **For jwt scheme only refresh tokens are revoked, since actual tokens
>   are never saved in the database

Here is the logout method for Adonisjs 4.1

```
 async logout({ request, response, auth }) { 

        const refreshToken = request.input('refreshToken');
        if(!refreshToken){

            // You can throw any exception you want here
            throw BadRequestException.invoke(`Refresh Token missing`);
        }

        await auth
          .authenticator('jwt')
          .revokeTokens([refreshToken], true)

      return response.send({status : 200, "message" : 'success'})
  }
```